# What's a good word for 'A short review'?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

This would be a topic in a progress report that would outline what the project is about without going into details.
I'm looking for something that means like 'Refresher' but sounds more professional.

Comment: "Overview" could work.

Comment: Summary, is your word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the term **[precis](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/precis)** (or *précis*)

> a summary of the essentials of a text; abstract

[from *Collins English Dictionary*]

Also

> - apercu (also *aperçu*, but some would not consider this English)
> - synopsis

Comment: Yes. Thank you. 'Abstract' was indeed what I was looking for. But 'précis' sounds even better.

Answer (score 1):

Compendium
Conspectus
Synopsis

Comment: +1 for compendium, it pairs well with conclusion (two things commonly found in the same works)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an abstract? [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_(summary)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_%28summary%29)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the term  [survey](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Survey):

> A gathering of a sample of data or opinions considered to be representative of a whole.

or  [summary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Summary)

> A presentation of the substance of a body of material in a condensed form or by reducing it to its main points.
>
> A brief statement that presents the main points in a concise form; "he gave a summary of the conclusions"

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/

Answer (score 0):

Outline - A general description or plan showing the essential features of something but not the detail.

Look it up in oxford

Answer (score 0):

I recommend "a brief".  As a noun, it means a short summary, and it's common in legal discussions.