# Is there a specific term for the short descriptions of a movie or TV episode present in TV guides?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, cinema

In TV guides, there are often short descriptions of movies or episodes of a TV series, like the [one pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGY85.jpg):

> The Wizard of Oz. (8-10 p.m., TCM)
> —Transported to a surreal landscape, a young girl kills the first person she meets and then teams up with three strangers to kill again.

Is there a specific term for this kind of text?

Comment: It's called a "summary" or a "short summary."  Sometimes, people call it a "blurb," as in, "Did you read the blurb below the title?"

Comment: Wow, I never thought of "The Wizard of Oz" in those terms!

Comment: @StevenLittman Have you thought of it terms of a political analogy of the times in which it was written?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good word for 'A short review'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182930/whats-a-good-word-for-a-short-review)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It could be called a [synopsis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synopsis)

*3 a brief summary of the plot of a novel, motion picture, play, etc.*

Answer (score 8):

This is the [*blurb*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+blurb).

Originally the term used for a brief description of a book printed on its back cover to entice browsers to purchase it.  The term is now widely used for short promotional descriptions of films, television programmes and other media.

Comment: Except a blurb is for advertising; these are factual descriptions from a listings magazine. Can you show that the word still applies.

Answer (score 4):

It can also be called a log line. See this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_line) entry

> A **log line** or **logline** is a brief (usually one-sentence) summary of a television program, film, or book that states the central conflict of the story, often providing both a synopsis of the story's plot, and an emotional "hook" to stimulate interest. **A one-sentence program summary in TV Guide is a log line**

Answer (score 1):

A fancier term would be [***précis***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pr%C3%A9cis) (from MW):

> a concise summary of essential points, statements, or facts

Answer (score 1):

The term many professional film critics and sub-editors use is **capsule review**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_review) :

> A **capsule review** is a form of criticism, usually associated with
> journalism, that offers a relatively short critique of a specified
> artistic work (movie, music album, restaurant, painting, etc.).
> Capsule reviews generally appear in publications like newspapers and
> magazines, and can range anywhere from just a few sentences up to
> around 300 words. [...]

Comment: Hi Gounaman, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *capsule review* (linked to the source) and/or examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Most of the ones I see are not, in fact, capsule reviews, but short summaries of the plot, so perhaps *capsule summary* would be more accurate.

Comment: The person writing it often won't have seen the program (obviously if the program is live), so it's not going to be truly a review.

Answer (score 0):

This [**deadpan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpan)*, humorous [synopsis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synopsis) of "The Wizard of Oz" was written by Rick Polito, "penned for the *Marin Independent Journal* [Marin County is in northern California, just across the Golden Gate Bridge from San Francisco] and named by the *LA Times* as TV Listing of the Week when it was written in 1998."

See: https://www.imdb.com/news/ni39278186

The article goes on to say:

> "Polito jokes with Jim Romenesko in an interview, 'That line is going to follow me to the grave. It was just on Leno, it was a clue in a
>   crossword puzzle, it showed up in Playboy, and people use it as their
>   email sigs. Someday I’m going to walk down the street and see it on a T-shirt and punch the person who’s wearing it.'”

The real question is, why are so many *TV Guide* and newspaper synopses also so deadpan and hilarious in their listings? At least we know Polito was intentionally trying to be funny, but what about all the others? Is the job of creating TV and movie listings so interminably boring that the writers have to throw in zingers like this in order not to lose their minds?

*A site called [Educalingo](https://educalingo.com/en/dic-en/deadpan) includes this definition of deadpan:

> Deadpan is a form of comic delivery in which humor is presented without a change in emotion or body language. It is usually spoken in a casual, monotone or cantankerous voice, and expresses a calm, sincere or grave demeanor, often in spite of the ridiculousness of the subject matter.

Comment: That link has rotted, but imdb has the quote at https://www.imdb.com/news/ni39278186

Comment: Thanks, Davo. I had forgotten I penned that answer.

Comment: This is certainly a synopsis of the film, but often what a TV guide says will be something else that isn't primarily a summary of the film/show (some guides seem to pride themselves on barely mentioning the show at all). I guess this is a problem with the question though.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a log line. Log lines are a single sentence that typically include the protagonist, antagonist, inciting incident, and general idea of the story. It also helps if it makes you want to read the script the log line is about.

Source: [The Do's and Don'ts of Writing a Logline for Your Film or Video Project](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/writing-logline-for-film-video-project/)

Answer (score -3):

I would like to resurrect this thread to say that, while I am very grateful for the responses, I can't help but feel like I didn't find the answer I was looking for xD

My best guess is the word premise.

"What Is a Premise?

A story’s premise is the foundational idea that expresses the plot in simple terms. A good premise will communicate your story’s essence in a one-sentence or two-sentence statement."
https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-ensure-your-story-has-a-strong-premise

Comment: I kind of agree with this, but it shouldn't be posted as an answer - can you edit the question to say this?

Comment: The **premise** is a fixed part of a show's description: "The original premise of the show [House] was of a team of doctors working together trying to 'diagnose the undiagnosable'". It's mainly for those unfamiliar with the show. Although it can serve to introduce a movie, play, or book synopsis, it would be omitted in episode-by-episode synopses of a series.